# Load data from XML to List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I managed to create an XML file using JAXB with the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <data>
        <id>1000</id>
        <age>10</age>
        <values>
            <value>646.2</value>
            <value>637.44</value>
        </values>
        <dates>
            <date>2014-06-05</date>
            <date>2014-06-04</date>
        </dates>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>1001</id>
        <age>10</age>
        <values>
            <value>546.4</value>
            <value>541.5</value>
        </values>
        <dates>
            <date>2014-06-05</date>
            <date>2014-06-04</date>
        </dates>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>1002</id>
        <age>12</age>
        <values>
            <value>40.59</value>
            <value>40.21</value>
        </values>
        <dates>
            <date>2014-06-05</date>
            <date>2014-06-04</date>
        </dates>
    </data>
</person>
```

My person class:

```
public class Person {

   private final SimpleStringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty();
   private final SimpleIntegerProperty age = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

   private List<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
   private List<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();

   public String getId() {
       return id.get();
  }

   @XmlElement(name = "id")
   public void setId(String id) {
       this.id.set(id);
   }

   public Integer getAge() {
       return age.get();
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "age")
   public void setAge(Integer age) {
       this.age.set(age);
   } 

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "values")
   @XmlElement(name = "value")
   public List<Double> getValue() {
       return value;
   }

   public void setValue(List<Double> value) {
       this.value = value;
   } 

   @XmlElementWrapper(name = "dates")
   @XmlElement(name = "date")
   public List<String> getDates() {
       return date;
   }

   public void setDates(List<String> date) {
       this.date = date;
   }
}
```

My list wrapper class (as no annotation allowed for observable list):

```
@XmlRootElement(name = “person”)
public class ListWrapper {

    private List<Person> persons;

    public PersonListWrapper() {
        persons = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();
    }

    public void setPerson(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = “data”)
    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return this.persons;
    }
}
```

Parts of my main app, incl. unmarshalling method:

```
private ObservableList<Person> pData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

.

```
public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
    return this.pData;
}
```

.

```
   public void loadFile (File file) {
        JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = jaxb.createUnmarshaller();
        ListWrapper wr = (ListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);
        pData.clear();
        pData.addAll(wr.getPerson());
    }
```

Parts of my javafx controller class:

```
public void initializePersonTable() {   
idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("id"));
ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("age"));
}
```

.

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
    this.personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
}
```

.

```
private void NewPersonButton(ActionEvent event) {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setSymbol(personTF.getText()); // personTF = JavaFX Textfield
    p.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(ageTF.getText())); // ageTF = JavaFX Textfield
    mainApp.getPersonData().add(p);
}
```

When I load a saved XML file, the "id" and "age" are being added to a tableview via the observable list. How can I access the "value" and "date" data after loading the file? I want to use the data to create statistics.

If I eg. use:

```
Person p = new Person();
System.out.println(p.getDates());
```

... I just get an empty List returned

Comment: You should post some more code, so we can see where the problem lies, especially the creation of the person instances would be helpful.

Comment: Hi dhiller. Just did. Let me know if you need more details. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

greenhorn problems... I found a solution myself:

```
private void Test{
    for (Person p : personTable.getItems()) {
        System.out.println(p.getDates());
        System.out.println(p.getValues());
    }
```